# How can I include a script with document.write?

Tags: javascript, document.write

We need to add a script to our web application. It basically adds an corporate menu.

So we've received a script to include in the body of our web application:

```
<!-- BEGIN NAVIGATION -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://intranet.local/?getCorporateJsMenu"></script>
<!-- END NAVIGATION -->
```

And the content of https://intranet.local/?getCorporateJsMenu basically looks like this:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>');
//....
document.write('<div>');
document.write('<ul>');
//...
document.write('<li><a href="...">...</a></li>');
//...
document.write('</ul>');
document.write('</div>');
```

After having placed the `<!--NAVIGATION--><script...` directly into the HTML body, we were experiencing severe page load performance problems.

So our idea was to add the menu with JavaScript, when everything has already been loaded with something like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://intranet.local/?getCorporateJsMenu';
var domparent = jQuery('#header').get();
domparent[0].appendChild(script);
```

**With [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) we see, that the script element has been added to the HTML content and the script has been loaded from the network, but somehow the document.write of the loaded script doesn't get executed. Why?**

---

We cannot modify the contents of https://intranet.local/?getCorporateJsMenu since it comes from third party.

Comment: doc.write will hose performance. you can redefine the method and collect the calls in an array to achieve a poor-man's output buffering. then something like .innerHTML=arrWrites.join(" ");

Comment: @dandavis Actually `document.write()` is the fastest way to create content dynamically...

Comment: @Teemu: i don't know about creating content, or how you define "fastest", but doc.write has well-documented terrible effects on page load performance...

Comment: @dandavis Yep, when using it wrong... Anyway, I agree with the opinion that OP's task can (and should) be done without `document.write()`.

Comment: @JMW After your update, it looks like your only chance is to contact the vendor, and ask them to fix the script, or change the vendor...

Comment: @Teemu is there a way to override document.write to make the script will work?

Comment: I can't see any way to override a third-party code, since you can't access a cross-domain document. And in this particular case, the error is caused at the parse time, you couldn't heal it even if it was your own code, without correcting the code in the actual file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of hijacking document.write() to bring 21st century loading performance to legacy scripts:

```
<script>
    var writes = [];
    document.write = [].push.bind(writes);
</script>

<div id=targ></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://intranet.local/?getCorporateJsMenu"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("targ").innerHTML = writes.join(" ");
</script>
```

I've used the patterns to support ads on a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) site, as well as to cache embeds, and in one case to modify the content's style before injecting.

Comment: @Teemu: good code doesn't use document.write, so i don't see how this affects anything besides document.write() and script that use it...

Comment: I mean: `d.w('blaah'); var foo = 0; d.w('some ' + foo + ' is  coming');`. What would happen to the non-document.write-code in your snippet?

Comment: @Teemu: it would execute the same as any other normal script, and when you innerHTML'd, the concat stuff would be in there.  i really don't understand what you're getting at...

Comment: Great solution :-) But sadly, Teemu is right. the proposed solution doesn't work, because there is some javascript between the doc.writes, that attaches mouseover event handlers to the elements and doesn't find the html :-(

Comment: however, i will accept your answer, because it makes the document.writes work even though it is not a practical solution to our problem :-)

Comment: @JMW: i thought of something. my replacement is dead simple. you could rewrite it to push the string to thisScriptTag.parentNode.innerHTML/appendChild, in which case the generated contents should be visible to the "middle script".

Answer (score 14):

This happens because the script execution stops at the first found literal `</script>` tag, no matter if it was enclosed in the parenthesis. You need to obfuscate the ending `script` tag, for example:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="..."><\/script>');
```

However, it seems you use also jQuery. Why not use the jQuery methods to load a script and add the content to a page rather than `document.write()`?

Comment: Why is there restriction in place? What is the purpose? And whom does it help anyway, if people can ultimately work their way around like this?

Comment: @SandeepanNath Actually it's not a restriction, it's due to the behavior of an interpreter. When ever an interpreter meets an ending script tag, it's interpreted  – well  – as an ending script tag. That's why an at runtime written ending tag has to look different from the actual ending tag.

Comment: Thanks for the practical answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="..."></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Comment: This is what I do to check to make sure jQuery works. During the first time that I saw actual websites use this, I thought it was really funny.